# Preview activerecord queries in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a way to preview queries in the Rails console without executing them?

Edit: I would like to be able to preview destructive queries without executing them:

```
u = User.first
d = User.open_documents.first
```

I'd like to preview this without execution:

```
u.open_documents.delete(d)
```

The proposed answer of adding .to_sql at the end of the expression works for

```
u.open_documents.to_sql
```

but when called on

```
u.open_documents.delete(d).to_sql
```

executes the delete(!) and produces an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sql' for #<Array:0x585e4a8>
```

when called like this, I also get an error:

```
u.open_documents.first.to_sql
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sql' for #<Array:0x585e4a8>
```

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: In what way do you want to preview it? Do you just want to see what SQL would be generated?

Comment: Yes, I want to see the sql generated without it being executed. Esp. for destructive queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call .to_sql on an ActiveRecord::Relation to see the SQL that would be executed.

```
User.where(:id => 4).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"id\" = 4"
```

Also, the console will only automatically execute the relation (and instantiate the objects) if it's the last command on the line, so you can do this:

```
relation = User.where(:id => 4); 1
=> 1
```

and thus set a variable to the relation without running it.

I'm not actually sure which of these two you wanted to do, but they're both handy tricks.

Comment: .to_sql looks good, just wish it would work on associations. It works for  u = User.where(id: 2).to_sql and u.open_documents.to_sql but not for u.open_documents.first nor u.open_documents.delete(document).to_sql. Is there anything that would let me preview such quieries?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to preview sql for .first or .delete, but it does work with associations, e.g. `Users.join(:posts => :comments).where(:id => 4).to_sql`

Comment: Although I suppose if you're using a database that supports transactions, like PostgreSQL, and print SQL in the console when it's executed (the latest version of rails does this automatically, and there's ways to make older ones do it as well), you could start a transaction, execute the query, and then raise an exception to rollback the transaction. That's a pretty horrible hack, but I guess it would work.

Comment: Thank you. Seems that the pure-rails solution is .to_sql.